# can put alias in fulltext query?

Tags: full-text-search

This is FULLTEXT query, searching food from restaurants-menu

```
$query = "SELECT *, MATCH(food_row) AGAINST('cheese' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS yyy
          FROM table_menu 
          WHERE MATCH(food_row) AGAINST('cheese' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
          AND restaurant IN (SELECT id FROM table_restaurant 
                             WHERE country IN ('FR') AND town='paris')";
```

I want to modify. Considering Max distance = 5km. this is working.
latitude and longitude are of user (google geocode), lat and lng of restaurants in mysql (they are in table_restaurant)

```
$xxx = " (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
        sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
        cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `lng`)
        *pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) ";

$query .= " AND ($xxx <= 5 )"; // 5 = the max distance
```

yes working, but I can't write each restaurant distance in the output. 
I don't know how insert 'AS distance' If not FULLTEXT, would be easy.

```
$query = "SELECT *, $xxx as distance FROM table2 WHERE ... ORDER BY distance ";
```

output: distance = row['distance']

how can I do? Sorry for my english, tanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason you're modifying the query is because the distance test is optional.
Try it like this:

```
if ($max_dist) {
    $dist = " (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
            sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
            cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `lng`)
            *pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) ";
    $having = "HAVING distance < $max_dist";
} else {
    $dist = " NULL ";
    $having = '';
}
$query = "SELECT m.*, MATCH(food_row) AGAINST('cheese' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS yyy,
                 $dist AS distance
          FROM table_menu m
          JOIN table_restaurant r ON m.restaurant = r.id
          WHERE MATCH(food_row) AGAINST('cheese' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
          AND country IN ('FR') AND town='paris'
          $having";
```

Comment: thanks, but not working. Think because fields 'lat' and 'lng' are not in table_menu, but in table_restaurant

Comment: `JOIN` with `table_restaurant` instead of `restaurant IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Not working '$dist' contains fields 'lat' and 'lng', who are in table_restaurant, while '$query = SELECT ... $dist AS distance FROM table_menu' is it right? Thanks